# Poco::Uint32 and Mactypes Uint32 are ambiguous

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, poco

In ios usr/include/MacTypes.h there is a

```
typedef unsigned long  UInt32;
```

and In Poco/Types.h there is also

```
typedef unsigned int  UInt32;
```

And when i try to compile it gives and error as :

```
Reference to "Uint32" is ambiguous
```

[In this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706281/typedef-redefinition-of-uint32-in-mactypes-h-from-definition-in-cfbase-h) the guy has exactly same problem as me. But i didnt understand the solution. So is there anybody knows a solution ?

*Note : I didnt include directly Poco/Types.h. This was included from another header file. And MacTypes.h was included by another library header file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem, if you face with this problem you should change order of importing headers. You should import Poco headers after native headers.

Comment: You should always do that anyway.